# problems traversing ne chunks in NLTK3

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

Hi Im trying this code in NLTK3:-
Somehow I managed to fix line-6 to work with version 3 of NLTK. But stil the for loop doesnt return anything at all.

```
import nltk
sample = """ some random text content with names and countries etc"""     
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sample)
tokenized_sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences=nltk.chunk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences) #Managed to fix this to work with version_3

for i in chunked_sentences:
    if hasattr(i,'label'):
        if i.label()=='NE':
            print i
```

Also if I try to debug , I see this output :

```
for i in chunked_sentences:
    if hasattr(i,'label') and i.label:
        print i.label
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
```

Then how do I check it for "NE". Theres something wrong with NLTK-3 that Im really not able to figure out.Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are iterating over sentences. I assume you want to iterate over the individual nodes contained in sentences.

It should work like this:

```
for sentence in chunked_sentences:
    for token in sentence: 
       if hasattr(token,'label') and token.label() == 'NE':
           print token
```

Edit: For future reference, what tipped me off to the fact that you are iterating over sentences is simply that the root node for a sentence is commonly labeled 'S'.

Comment: Thanks, strangely I had to replace "NE" by "PERSON" for it to output (while lot many people have mentioned "NE") . Any reasons ? :       if hasattr(token,'label') and token.label() == 'PERSON':

Comment: @rzach 'PERSON', as you probably know, is kind of a special case of 'NE'. I took a look at the code for [ne_chunk_sents](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk.html#ne_chunk_sents). If you set ``binary=True``, it will likely return 'NE'. The default is ``binary=False`` in which case a more fine-grained model is used. These models typically distinguish between PERSON, LOCATION and so on. I'm not sure about the particular classes in that NLTK implementation, however.

Comment: Ohh ofcourse here you go. Can you also pls help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201418/data-preparation-feature-selection-for-named-entity-using-svm

Comment: @rzach I can't comment on your link. Can you edit that question to include some details on research papers and what you are trying to classify? E.g. what is your input, what is your output (which classes)? What SVM package?